# Get value from jQuery AJAX to PHP

Tags: php, jquery

Working on a project where I want to be able to delete a dynamic record using `jQuery` and `PHP`. I already have the option for users to add a record dynamically it is just getting the delete option to work. While I am trying to develop this function I have set the `Delete` to `INSERT`. Where I am having trouble is getting the value from the hidden field to `delete-class.php` (the bottom script). Below I have posted the code:

```
<form id="frmDelete" method="post" action="delete-class.php">
            <input id="btnSubmit" type="submit"/> 

            <ul id="class">
                <?php
//this is being loaded from a different page and is here just to reference the fields
                 while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                 echo '<li id="liClass" class="ui-widget"><img src="trash-can-icon.png" id='.$row["id_distance_class"].' class="delete"/>' . $row["class_section"] . '<input type="hidden" name="hdid" id="hdid" value="'.$row["id_distance_class"].'"/></li>';
                ?>
            </ul>
        </form>
<script>
        $(function() {
            $(".delete").click(function() {
                $('#load').fadeIn();
                var commentContainer = $(this).parent();
                var id = $(this).attr("id");
                var string = id ;
                // console.log(id);

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "delete-class.php",
                    data: $(this).serialize(),
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(){
                        commentContainer.slideUp('slow', function() {$(this).remove();});
                        $('#load').fadeOut();
                    }
                });
                return false;
            });
        });
    </script>
//this is the delete-class.php
$results = mysql_query("INSERT INTO distance_class (class_section) VALUES ( '".$_POST['hdid']."' ) ");
```

Comment: The values are passed to delete-class.php via `POST`. What's the question?

Comment: Also, it may not help answer your question, but you should stop using `mysql_*` functions. They're being deprecated. Instead use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) or [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: When debugging something like this in the future, do a print_r on $_POST to see what you are getting.

Comment: Thanks Matt I typically use PDO in most projects. But I am updating an existing application and wanted to keep the coding consistant throughout. With that said I do plan to convert all existing mysql_* to PDO.

Comment: The POST value is not being passed. But I set up the btnSubmit to debug and see what values were being passed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're not passing this information in your AJAX request. You're passing

```
data: $(this).serialize()
```

...presumably thinking `this` points to the form. It doesn't; it points to the deletion button clicked, since this code is running in the button's event handler callback.

Change the above to target the form.

Comment: If I wanted to pass the using var id = $this.(#hdid).val(); would that be possible. I am struggling with the jQuery part.

Comment: `data: {hdid: $('#hdid').val()}` - that will send a post param to your PHP, named `hdid`